# Кто знает как настроить webpack для react, что бы devServer отображал так же как и с create-react-app, с отображением ошибок(когда красный экран)?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Кто знает как настроить webpack для react, что бы devServer отображал так же как и с create-react-app, с отображением ошибок(когда красный экран)? а сча когда ошибка, на экране просто картинка проекта и ошибка только в консоли.
Что бы могло показывать ошибки как на картинке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HTMLwebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')
const TerserWebpackPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const {BundleAnalyzerPlugin} = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer')

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';// проверка если в режиме разработки
const isProd = !isDev;





const cssLoader = (extra) => {
  const loaders = [
    {
      loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
      options: {
        hmr: isDev, //изменять сущности без перезагрузки страницы
        reloadAll: true,
        publicPath: '../',
      },
    }, {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        url: true,
      }
    }];

  if (extra) {
    loaders.push(extra)
  }

  return loaders
}



module.exports = {
  context: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), // путь с какой папки и убирается он ниже с путей
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    main: [ './index.jsx'],
    // main: ['@babel/polyfill', './index.jsx'], // если нужна поддержка старых браузеров
    // analytics: './analytics.ts'
  },
  output: {
    filename: isDev ? `js/[name].js` : `js/[name].[contenthash:8].chunk.js`,
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
  },
  devServer: { // сохраняет в кеш
    port: 4200, // life перезагрузка webpack-dev-server когда сохраняешь нужно --open для открытия браузера
    hot: isDev
  },
  devtool: isDev ? 'source-map' : '', // map для sass
  optimization: {
    moduleIds: 'hashed',
    splitChunks: {
      chunks: "all",  // чтобы  чанки одинаковые не вставлялись каждый раз в компонент
      name:false,
    },
    minimizer:[].concat(
        isProd ?
       [ new OptimizeCssAssetPlugin(), // оптимизация для прода css
        new TerserWebpackPlugin()]
        : []
    )
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'], // чтобы не дописывать окончания когда import и какие
    // alias: {
    //   '@model': path.resolve(__dirname,'src') // указывать более короткие пути когда import
    // }
  },
  plugins: [
    new HTMLwebpackPlugin({ // создание html в build c генерированными скриптами
      template: "./index.html",
      minify: {
        collapseWhitespace: isProd // оптимизация html build
      }
    }),
    new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(), // чистка build перед сборкой
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([ // перенос файлов тут иконка
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/favicon.ico'),
        to: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build')
      }
    ]),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({ // закидывать в build css
      filename:  isDev ? `[name].css` :  'css/[name].[hash:8].css',
    }),
  ]
  //     .concat(
  //     isProd ? new BundleAnalyzerPlugin() : []
  // )
  ,
  module: {
    rules: [

      {
        test: /\.css$/, //регулярка
        use: cssLoader(),
        // use: ['style-loader','css-loader'] //style-loader добавление css в html
        // если совподение с регул то выполн use

      },

      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|svg|gif)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          outputPath: 'img',

        }

      },
      {
        test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot)$/,
        use: ['file-loader']
      },

      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: cssLoader('less-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: cssLoader('sass-loader')
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          presets: [
            '@babel/preset-env',
            '@babel/preset-typescript'
          ],
          plugins: [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {

              presets: [
                '@babel/preset-env',
                '@babel/preset-react'
              ],
              plugins: [
                "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
              ],

            }
          }, 'eslint-loader'
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: максимум что нашел это  overlay: true, в devServer установить, но он налаживает ошибки на твой сайт

Comment: ну как бы решил вопрос   plugins: [
    new ErrorOverlayPlugin(),